SwiftUI Top Toolbar button for child view appears multiple times during swiping
In a SwiftUI application I am working with, I have a TabView that I use with paginated style. Each Page of the TabView is a full screen item and each every one of those pages have some action button placed on navigation bar on top (top trailing).
The problem I am facing this is, when I keep on swiping between the pages, the navigation button multiplies for split second as it is displaying the next or previous page's toolbar buttons together. After half a second or so it only shows the current page's button only.
Attached below is screen recording of the problem and the sample code to demonstrate.
https://ibb.co/kBQ30n0  (sorry I can't upload gif file to SO as it gives error)
import SwiftUI

struct Model: Identifiable {
    internal init(id: UUID = .init(), position: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.position = position
        self.color = .red
    }
    
    let id: UUID
    var position: Int
    var color: Color
    var title: String { return "item: \(position)" }
    var shortTitle: String { return "\(position)" }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView {
                ForEach(viewModel.models) { model in
                    Modelview(model: model)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
            .navigationTitle("Title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

struct Modelview: View {
    var model: Model
    var body: some View {
        
        Rectangle().fill(model.color)
            .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                Text(model.title).font(.title).foregroundStyle(.black)
                    .padding().background(in: .rect, fillStyle:  .init())
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {}, label: { Text(model.shortTitle) })
                }
            }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var models: [Model] = []
    
    init() {
        let count = 30
        var items: [Model] = []
        for i in 0..<count {
            items.append(.init(position: i+1))
        }
        self.models = items
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


If anyone has encountered a similar problem and found a better way to handle the situation, I really appreciate any helpful tips.
In summary, what needs to happen is, for a similar full page swipe between events, the navigation bar buttons need to be customised based on current page's content. The demonstrated code is for a very simple use case, but totally reproducible.
Update 1
Due to the nature of the problem, the toolbar options are difficult to be managed on the parent view with TabView / ScrollView is and it's best provided by the child view itself. (Toolbar options are dynamic based on the type of item the model is, it's internal processing state and some other business logic, which are all managed by a viewmodel managed by each childview itself)
Update 2
TabView is used because of iOS16 support. If however we replace it with a ScrollView with scrollTargetBehaviour the problem with toolbar still remains at large.
Thanks

TabView should not be inside a NavigationStack. Can you use a ScrollView with .paging behaviour instead, or do you need to support iOS 16?

Yes the whole reason to go with TabView with paging is due to iOS 16 limitation.

Well then you'd need to wrap a UIPageViewController with a UIViewControllerRepresentable then.

Thanks, just a note on that. The methods above won't actually fix the problem I'm facing with the navigation buttons. (It in-fact worsens it by showing 4 permanent buttons belonging to neighbouring pages without even removing after page swipe is completed)

As mentioned, TabView should not be inside a NavigationStack.
You could try a different approach using a simple HStack and TabView(selection: $selectedModel) to replicate your desired UI.
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    @State private var selectedModel: Model?  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // --- here
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Title")
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    print("---> clicked on \(selectedModel?.shortTitle ?? "1")")
                }, label: {
                    Text("\(selectedModel?.shortTitle ?? "1")")
                }).padding(8)
            }
            TabView(selection: $selectedModel) {  // <--- here
                ForEach(viewModel.models) { model in
                    Modelview(model: model).tag(model)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
        }
    }
}

struct Modelview: View {
    var model: Model
    var body: some View {
        
        Rectangle().fill(model.color)
            .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                Text(model.title).font(.title).foregroundStyle(.black)
                    .padding().background(in: .rect, fillStyle:  .init())
            }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var models: [Model] = []
    
    init() {
        let count = 30
        var items: [Model] = []
        for i in 0..<count {
            items.append(.init(position: i+1))
        }
        self.models = items
    }
}

struct Model: Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    internal init(id: UUID = .init(), position: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.position = position
        self.color = .red
    }
    
    let id: UUID
    var position: Int
    var color: Color
    var title: String { return "item: \(position)" }
    var shortTitle: String { return "\(position)" }
}


Thanks. We used to have a simpler structure where the button could be placed on parent view with respect to a selection variable. But sadly the childView's has become very complicated and dynamic where the toolbar options are driven through model and it's internal processing state which is not available to the parent view where the tabview / scrollview is.  But seems like there is no easy way to fix up the toolbar button problem and I may have to use a standard set of buttons placed on the childview itself. Thanks again for your response.
